# Права доступа к директории для пользователя

Tags: linux, ftp, доступ

Есть у меня пользователь `vasya` и домашняя директория его `/home/vasya`. Можно ли сделать нового пользователя `petya`, но чтобы его домашняя директория была `/home/vasya/trampampam/petya` таким образом, чтобы он не мог видеть всё что выше его домашней директории.

Либо каким образом можно дать фтп доступ к только определённой папке с запретом подниматься на уровень выше?

ОС `Ubuntu Server`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создать пользователей можно так:

```
user@server: sudo useradd vasya
user@server: sudo useradd -d /home/vasya/trampampam/petya petya
```

Почитать можно [здесь](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B) (см. ключ `-d`).

А для того, чтобы запереть пользователя в домашней директории, можно использовать настройку `chroot_local_user` в [`vsftpd.conf`](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html).

**UPD.** Если надо запретить выход из домашней деректории только пользователю `petya`, то надо:

1) В `vsftpd.conf` прописать:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
```

2) Добавить пользователя `vasya` в файл `/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это единственный способ? Мне по сути нужен только фтп.
И где находится файл vsftpd.conf? И не будет ли эти настройка распространяться на всех пользователей?

Comment: @Jeid `/etc/vsftpd.conf`. Эти настройки распространяются на пользователей, перечисленных в `/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list`. Остальные, ЕМНИП, вообще не смогут подключиться по ftp.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Как я понял для этого сначала надо установить vsftpd

Comment: @andy.37 какие 'эти' настройки?

Comment: @Jeid а какой ftp сервер у тебя поднят?

Comment: @MichaelPak, это был ответ на вопрос "И не будет ли эти настройка распространяться на всех пользователей?". (см 1-й комментарий). Конкретно, настройки `chroot_*`

Comment: @andy.37, я может чего то не понимаю, но ты не прав.  Если у настроек `chroot_local_user` и `chroot_list_enable ` стоят значения `YES`, то в `chroot_list_file` будут те пользователи, которые не в `chroot() jail`.

Comment: @MichaelPak пока никакого, поэтому рассмотрю все варианты

Comment: @Jeid самый популярный - это `vsftpd`

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось!

Comment: @Jeid обращайтесь ;)